# How does my compiler find the stat (file status) function?

Tags: c, linker, llvm, glibc, llvm-ir

I have the following C program:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct stat fileStat;
    if(stat(argv[1],&fileStat) < 0)    
        return 1;
}
```

When I compile it to LLVM IR using Clang, I can see that `stat` is declared as following:

```
declare i32 @stat(i8*, %struct.stat*)
```

Usually, such an external call to a system function directly maps to a C standard library function. For example, I can find `malloc` with the following:

```
nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep malloc
```

However, the `stat` function seems to be treated differently. When grepping for `stat`, I can find related functions such as `__xstat` but not the `stat` function itself.

When I trace the call to the external library with `ltrace` I see the following call: `__xstat(1, ".", 0x7fff7928c6f0)`. Also the code in the executable confirms that instead of calling the `stat` function the `__xstat` function is called.

I did not observe other function calls to the C standard library that have other names than those declared in the C program. Why is there no direct equivalent in the standard library and how does my compiler find out that it should produce a call to `__xstat` and not to `stat`?

Comment: This may helps you a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237294/intercepting-stat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Header `sys/stat.h` defines `stat` as a macro that calls `__xstat` in glibc:

```
#define stat(fname, buf) __xstat (_STAT_VER, fname, buf)
```

Comment: But if `stat` is a macro, then the macro should already be resolved by Clang and the call in the LLVM bitcode file should go to `__xstat` or not?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following comment in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h`:

```
/* To allow the `struct stat' structure and the file type `mode_t'
   bits to vary without changing shared library major version number,
   the `stat' family of functions and `mknod' are in fact inline
   wrappers around calls to `xstat', `fxstat', `lxstat', and `xmknod',
   which all take a leading version-number argument designating the
   data structure and bits used.  <bits/stat.h> defines _STAT_VER with
   the version number corresponding to `struct stat' as defined in
   that file; and _MKNOD_VER with the version number corresponding to
   the S_IF* macros defined therein.  It is arranged that when not
   inlined these function are always statically linked; that way a
   dynamically-linked executable always encodes the version number
   corresponding to the data structures it uses, so the `x' functions
   in the shared library can adapt without needing to recompile all
   callers.  */

# ifdef __REDIRECT_NTH
extern int __REDIRECT_NTH (stat, (const char *__restrict __file,
                  struct stat *__restrict __buf), stat64)
     __nonnull ((1, 2));
# endif
```

`__REDIRECT_NTH` is defined in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h`:

```
/* __asm__ ("xyz") is used throughout the headers to rename functions
   at the assembly language level.  This is wrapped by the __REDIRECT
   macro, in order to support compilers that can do this some other
   way.  When compilers don't support asm-names at all, we have to do
   preprocessor tricks instead (which don't have exactly the right
   semantics, but it's the best we can do).

   Example:
   int __REDIRECT(setpgrp, (__pid_t pid, __pid_t pgrp), setpgid); */

#if defined __GNUC__ && __GNUC__ >= 2

# define __REDIRECT(name, proto, alias) name proto __asm__ (__ASMNAME (#alias))
# ifdef __cplusplus
#  define __REDIRECT_NTH(name, proto, alias) \
     name proto __THROW __asm__ (__ASMNAME (#alias))
#  define __REDIRECT_NTHNL(name, proto, alias) \
     name proto __THROWNL __asm__ (__ASMNAME (#alias))
# else
#  define __REDIRECT_NTH(name, proto, alias) \
     name proto __asm__ (__ASMNAME (#alias)) __THROW
#  define __REDIRECT_NTHNL(name, proto, alias) \
     name proto __asm__ (__ASMNAME (#alias)) __THROWNL
# endif
# define __ASMNAME(cname)  __ASMNAME2 (__USER_LABEL_PREFIX__, cname)
# define __ASMNAME2(prefix, cname) __STRING (prefix) cname
```

From the comments and macro definitions it seems that the alias is specified in inline assembler.